# Infinite and countdown counters

Tags: c#, iterator, interface

I'm refactoring my [scheduler](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/192103/scheduler-built-with-observables-v2-follow-up) and for one of its triggers I need an endless counter that would automatically restart. Since this is a simple and very common task I don't want to *ever* have to implement it again so I encapsulated it in such a way that it hopefully can be reused *everywhere* else.

---

The counter is represented by an enumerable interface with a couple or properties that provide information about the counter and methods allowing to interact with it.

```
public interface IInfiniteCounter : IEnumerable<(int Value, InfiniteCounterState State)>
{
    int Min { get; }

    int Max { get; }

    int Length { get; }

    int Current { get; }

    (int Value, InfiniteCounterState State) Next();

    void Reset();
}
```

It uses an `enum` to inform the caller about the type of the value. It returns `First` each time the counter restarted, `Intermediate` for values inbetween and `Last` for the last value.

```
public enum InfiniteCounterState
{
    First,
    Intermediate,
    Last,
}
```

---

I have one implementation of the interface. The `InfiniteCounter` that is a forward running counter:

```
public class InfiniteCounter : IInfiniteCounter
{
    private int _current;

    public InfiniteCounter(int min, int max)
    {
        Min = min;
        Max = max;
    }

    public InfiniteCounter(int max) : this(0, max) { }

    public int Min { get; }

    public int Max { get; }

    public int Length => Max - Min;

    public int Current => _current + Min;

    private bool IsLast => _current == Length;

    public (int Value, InfiniteCounterState State) Next()
    {
        if (IsLast)
        {
            Reset();
        }

        return
        (
            Current,
            _current++ == 0
                ? InfiniteCounterState.First
                : IsLast
                    ? InfiniteCounterState.Last
                    : InfiniteCounterState.Intermediate
        );
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        _current = 0;
    }

    public IEnumerator<(int Value, InfiniteCounterState State)> GetEnumerator()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            yield return Next();
        }
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();
}
```

In order to have it running backwards I created two extensions. One that is an extension for the `IInfiniteCounter`

```
public static class InfiniteCounterExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<(int Value, InfiniteCounterState State)> Countdown(this IInfiniteCounter counter)
    {
        return counter.Select(x => (x.Value.Flip(counter.Min, counter.Max), x.State));
    }
}
```

and one that is flipping the value:

```
public static class IndexMath
{
    public static int Flip(this int value, int min, int max)
    {
        return (-(value - max + 1) % (max - min)) + min;
    }
}
```

Examples:

```
void Main()
{
    var take = 4;
    new InfiniteCounter(3).Take(take).Dump("0-2");
    new InfiniteCounter(3).Countdown().Take(take).Dump("2-0");
    new InfiniteCounter(2, 5).Take(take).Dump("2-4");
    new InfiniteCounter(2, 5).Countdown().Take(take).Dump("4-2");

    0.Flip(0, 3).Dump();
    1.Flip(0, 3).Dump();
}
```

---

What do you think about it? It should be convenient to use and every piece of it should be testable. *(Argument checking will be added later)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> public interface IInfiniteCounter : IEnumerable<(int Value, InfiniteCounterState State)>
> ```

vs

> ```
>     int Current { get; }
>
>     (int Value, InfiniteCounterState State) Next();
>
>     void Reset();
> ```

The interface itself looks a lot more like `IEnumerator<>` than `IEnumerable<>`, so IMO implementing `IEnumerable<>` is misleading and dangerous. The docs for `IEnumerable<>` don't say either way whether or not it's possible to have two active enumerators at the same time, but I can't think of any implementations in the standard library for which it isn't possible, and I've probably written a lot of code which assumes that it is possible.

---

> ```
>     int Min { get; }
>
>     int Max { get; }
>
>     int Length { get; }
> ```

I can safely assume that `Min` is inclusive, but I absolutely need a comment to tell me whether `Max` is or not, and it would be helpful to have a comment indicating the standard implementation of `Length`. Also, should `Length` be `uint` both because it's guaranteed to be non-negative and to avoid overflow in edge cases?

---

> ```
> public static class IndexMath
> {
>     public static int Flip(this int value, int min, int max)
>     {
>         return (-(value - max + 1) % (max - min)) + min;
>     }
> }
> ```

I don't understand why this method uses `%`. For me the obvious interpretation of the name (and the use case) is `max - (value - min)`. If there's some trickery going on to avoid or handle overflow, it needs explanatory comments.

Comment: This is an interesting point with the enumerator thing... it's hard to decide which one it actually should be... I think it should be cleaner if `Next` wasn't part of the interface... oops, or not, I need this because it's not running in a loop but will be called by the scheduler on each tick... You're right, the `%` should fix the overflow of the `value`.

Answer (score 1):

[@Peter Taylor](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/214913/59161) is right. It was some strange enumerable/enumerator hybrid so I have turned it into a real `IEnumerator<T>` of itself because I think is makes it easier to use in various scenarios.

If I now want to have an `IEnumerable` I can use the new `AsEnumerable` extension and if I want to have a countdown then I can flip the value with new `ValueAsCountdown()` extension. The `State` has become `Position`.

It hasn't changed much but here's the full code (that I still need to document... later):

```
public interface IInfiniteCounter : IEnumerator<IInfiniteCounter>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the min value of the counter.
    /// </summary>
    int Min { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the max exclusive value of the counter.
    /// </summary>
    int Max { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the total length of the counter.
    /// </summary>
    int Length { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the current value of the counter.
    /// </summary>
    int Value { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the relative position of the counter between min and max.
    /// </summary>
    InfiniteCounterPosition Position { get; }
}

public class InfiniteCounter : IInfiniteCounter
{
    private int _value;

    public InfiniteCounter(int min, int max)
    {
        Min = min;
        Max = max;
        Reset();
    }

    public InfiniteCounter(int max) : this(0, max) { }

    public int Min { get; }

    public int Max { get; }

    public int Length => Max - Min;

    public int Value => _value + Min;

    IInfiniteCounter IEnumerator<IInfiniteCounter>.Current => this;

    object IEnumerator.Current => this;

    public InfiniteCounterPosition Position =>
        _value == 0
            ? InfiniteCounterPosition.First
            : _value == Length - 1
                ? InfiniteCounterPosition.Last
                : InfiniteCounterPosition.Intermediate;

    public bool MoveNext()
    {
        if (Position == InfiniteCounterPosition.Last)
        {
            Reset();
        }

        _value++;

        return true;
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        _value = -1;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        // There is nothing to dispose.
    }
}

public static class IndexMath
{
    public static int Flip(this int value, int min, int max)
    {
        return (-(value - max + 1) % (max - min)) + min;
    }
}

public static class InfiniteCounterExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<IInfiniteCounter> AsEnumerable(this IEnumerator<IInfiniteCounter> counter)
    {
        while (counter.MoveNext())
        {
            yield return counter.Current;
        }
    }

    public static int ValueAsCountdown(this IInfiniteCounter counter)
    {
        return counter.Value.Flip(counter.Min, counter.Max);
    }
}

public enum InfiniteCounterPosition
{
    First,
    Intermediate,
    Last,
}
```

Comment: I have small issue with InfiniteCounterPosition.  I guess you intend to have a proper range, and not have Min=Max, in which case a given position could be both the First and Last.

Comment: @RickDavin good point, I was thinking about restricting the _length_ to at least two elements. Otherwise it doesn't make sense to use it at all ;-)